# I'm trying to make a function that sorts a list using bubble sorting and returns the number of swaps

Tags: python-3.x

```
def improve_bubble_sort(list_of_values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_values)):
        for j in range(len(list_of_values)-1,i,-1):
            if list_of_values[j]<list_of_values[j-1]:
                count += 1
                bubble(values) 
    count += 1
    return count
```

I want to know whats wrong with this code, as when i test to print(improved_bubble_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) the count comes to 6 instead of 5 :/ the bubble(values) code refers to another code which is all correct. any help would be great thanks !!

Comment: What about extra `count += 1`  at the end of a method ?

Comment: where abouts ?? i already have a  count += 1 and then return count

Comment: If I do "`print(improve_bubble_sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))`" with your code, commenting out `bubble(values)`, it prints `1`. This should be `0` in this case, shouldn't it? Since no bubble sort should be done on that list of numbers? So the `count += 1` right before `return` shouldn't be there.

Comment: if I take out that count, it prints 1 instead of 2

Comment: What is your desired output? If you change the `<` in the `if` statement to `>`, it looks like you can get a reversed bubble sort.